# CCMenuItem independent from gesture recognicers view cocos 2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer, cclayer

I have a `CClayer` class, called GridLayer I add the gesture recognizers (**Pan ,Pinch and Rotate**) to the view and it works fine, but if i add a `CCMenuItem` is paste to the view so is affected by the rotate and pinch gestures , my question is who implement a independent `CCMenuitem` from the View Size ,Scale and position.

```
//Adding Rotation Recognicer onEnter Method
    self.rotationRecognicer =[[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self
                                                                          action:@selector(rotate:)]autorelease];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:_rotationRecognicer];

//Adding CCMenuItem On Init Method  
        CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                        itemWithNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.png"
                                        selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.png"
                                        target:self
                                    selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];

    starMenuItem.position = ccp(60, 60);
    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
    starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu];



//Rotation Method
- (void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }


}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are asking.. You want some GUI controls to not change their display when your grid layer is rotated or manipulated in some way?

Comment: Yes a grouped of controls floating in the screen of the device in a fixed position and independant from the grid gestures movement.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI controls need to exist on their own independent layer.

To accomplish this, you should add two separate layers to your CCScene container, or whatever is the parent node of your layer. This may look something like the following

```
@implementation SceneNode

@synthesize actionLayer;

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {

        UILayer * uiLayer = [UILayer node];

        self.actionLayer = [[ActionLayer alloc] initWithSceneUILayer:uiLayer];

        [self addChild:uiLayer z:UI_LAYER_Z_VALUE];
        [self addChild:actionLayer z:ACTION_LAYER_Z_VALUE];

    } // end if

    return self;


} // end init

@end
```

The tricky part is getting them to communicate without creating a tight coupling between the classes. It is likely you will want the action layer (your grid layer) to be informed when a control is interacted with on your GUI layer. This is where you will want to implement either the Command Design Pattern and or use Objective-C protocols with a delegate.

If you decide to use a protocol and delegate, it may look like the following

```
// In a header file
@protocol ControlsProtocols

-(void)fireButtonEvent;

-(void)angleSelectionEvent;

-(void)powerSelectionEvent:(int)powerRec;

@end
```

Create a delegate member data variable in the UILayer class

```
@interface ILayer : CCLayer {

    CCMenu * ControlsMenu;
    id <ControlsProtocols> delegate;

} // end ivar

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <ControlsProtocols> delegate;

@end
```

In your action layer (Grid Layer), which initializes with a pointer to the UILayer, assign itself as the delegate for the UILayer.

```
-(id)initWithSceneUILayer:(UILayer *)uiLayer {

    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {

        // Store reference to UILayer and set UILayer delegate to self
        UILayer = uiLayer;
        uiLayer.delegate = self;

        // More logic here

    } // end if 

    return self;

} // end init
```

Lastly, be sure to implement the protocol methods in the Action Layer (grid layer) class and move the gesture recognition to this layer. My guess is that you only want the action layer to be manipulated when certain gestures occur, not the view which houses your scene and layers. Add logic to capture the gestures in your Action Layer and only manipulate this layer's appearance instead of the entire view.

Comment: i have two separate CCLayer one is gridLayer and the other is Controls Layer , both are added to the same scene ,but the gesture actions acts on the **view** so both are affected for the action.

Comment: Could you not just move the gesture recognition to the layers which need it? Only your action layer should be scaled or manipulated not the view which contains the Scene and both layers.

Answer (score 0):

This approximation is based on the following example

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit

Creating a UIViewController called RootViewControler that contain all the controls needed 
and adding like subview the [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] with the gridLayer

```
//RootViewcontroler viewDidLoad Method:
    [self.view insertSubview:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] atIndex:0];
    CCScene *scene = [GridLayer scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector ]runWithScene: scene];
```

In the Appdelegate add the RootViewControler instance to the Navigation Controler

```
RootViewControler *rootViewcontroler =[[[RootViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

// Create a Navigation Controller 
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewcontroler];
```

Sure is not the unique posible solution, but for me works.